# how to verify if my datatable is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello again y have populate my datatable using 1 button an array, next button 2 is going to send my datatable to excel, so what a i do is this using C#, and asp.net:
out side of the button y declare my datable so i can be use in both buttons

```
    System.Data.DataTable _myDataTable =new System.Data.DataTable();
```

button 1 fill datatable: for this example lets say only 10 columns, caract=number of cells

```
for (int k=0; k < 10; k++) 
{
    _myDataTable.Columns.Add();   
}

for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
    {       
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    System.Data.DataRow row=_myDataTable.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < caract+1; i++)
    {
        row[i]=(datar[j,i].ToString());
    }
    _myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    Table1.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

now button 2 allows to the user if he wants to save the data from the datatable to an excel, but first i verifi if the datable is empty

```
if(_myDataTable !=null || _myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
    {

    string name="productos";
    Label2.Text="it has data";
            }
           else{Label2.Text="NO data"; }
```

no i recibe the text that i have data yupi for me, but when i press button 2 to send the datatable to excel, it creats the document however is empty,
so the next thing i would like to try is to verifi cell by cell if it has the data is supposed to have, but only have no idea how to extract the data from the datatable and to be display in a label. 
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 8):

Your `if` condition looks wrong on a couple of points.

This is how I would code it:

```
if(_myDataTable !=null && _myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
```

The above means - if `_myDataTable` is a valid object **and** it contains values.

Comment: Thanks with this i verify what i thought, my datatable is empty, so now i have to figure out how to send my datatable from button 1 to button 2

Answer (score 0):

JUAN you can define your DataTable in global scope. Then you can use it in both of your button event handlers.

For example:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private DataTable _myDataTable;
        public DataTable MyDataTable { 
            get 
            {
                return _myDataTable;
            } 
            set
            { 
                _myDataTable = value;
            } 
        }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int k=0; k < 10; k++) 
        {
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add();   
        }

        for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
        {       
            TableRow r = new TableRow();
            System.Data.DataRow row = MyDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < caract+1; i++)
            {
                row[i]=(datar[j,i].ToString());
            }
                MyDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                Table1.Rows.Add(r);
        }

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(MyDataTable !=null || MyDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {

            string name="productos";
            Label2.Text="it has data";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text="NO data"; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but there is an easy way to solve this right now as follows:

```
if ((dataTableName?.Rows?.Count ?? 0) > 0)
```